# jQuery Status Messages (Similar to Twitter)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, animation

I'm creating a status message bar with the following properties:

- Slides into view. Fades away after a certain time.
- If another status message is triggered, the currently-visible status message slides out of view, then the new one slides into view.

The problem I'm having is with the fading out. The fading out action doesn't seem to get dequeued, so a previous fade will apply to an ensuing status message. Any idea how to fix this?

```
function status_message(message, type, long_display) {
    if (!type) {
        type = SUCCESS;
    }
    var $status_message = $("#status_message");
    long_display ? display_time = 9000 : display_time = 3250;
    if ($status_message.is(":visible")) {
        $status_message.queue("fx", []).animate({top:-$(this).outerHeight()}, 500, "easeInCubic");
    }
    $status_message.show().queue(function() {
        $(this).html(message).css({'top': -$(this).outerHeight()}).addClass(type).dequeue();
    }).animate({top:"0px"}, 750, easing).delay(display_time).fadeOut(500, function () {
        $(this).animate({top:-$(this).outerHeight()}, 500, "easeInCubic").addClass(type);
    });
}
function status_message_hide() {
    $status_message.queue("fx", []).fadeOut(500, function () {
        $(this).animate({top:-$(this).outerHeight()}, 500, "easeInCubic");
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setTimeout() on the fade? So it always starts after a certain time?

Answer (score 0):

.stop() should do it if im understanding it right

http://api.jquery.com/stop/